# Magento 2 - Event after customer edit account and address

Tags: magento2, event-observer, customer, customer-account, customer-address

I need to add some custom logic in my extension after

1. Edit Account Information
2. Change Password
3. Edit Address

The `customer_save_after_data_object` event can be used for case 1. How about 2 & 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use below events for 3rd point.

> Edit Address

customer_address_save_after

```
<event name="customer_address_save_after">
    <observer name="customer_addres_after_save_viv_observer" instance="Magento\Customer\Observer\AfterAddressSaveObserver" />
</event>
```

or

customer_address_save_before

```
<event name="customer_address_save_before">
    <observer name="customer_address_before_save_viv_observer" instance="Magento\Customer\Observer\BeforeAddressSaveObserver" />
</event>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how can I get the address object in the observer?

Comment: $customerAddress = $observer->getCustomerAddress(); refer Magento\Customer\Observer\AfterAddressSaveObserver for more info.

Comment: how to distinguish whether the address is a billing address or a shipping address?

Comment: can we use this event for customer account info edit? "customer_account_edited"

Comment: It is good to know that the event is fired only when the data is changed.

Comment: customer_address_save_after event calls multiple times on Magento ver. 2.4.2-p2. Any idea on why this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

For 2, you can use the same event as 1: `customer_save_after_data_object`

For 3, you can use the `customer_address_save_after` event

Comment: How to get customer street after using that event?

Comment: customer_save_after_data_object is not firing when the account info  is asaved

Comment: How can get customer object in observer file?