# How to send mail when get events in observer?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, email, custom

I create **adminhtml/events.xml** and **frontend/events.html** with code content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="adminhtml_customer_save_after">
        <observer name="send_member_information_update_mail" instance="TTV\Blog\Observer\SendMemberInformationUpdateMail " />
    </event>
</config>
```

I declare **Observer/SendMemberInformationUpdateMail.php**

```
namespace TTV\Blog\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class SendMemberInformationUpdateMail implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        var_dump("Save By Customer");die;
    }
}
```

Please tell me:
  +To take events customer edit information or admin edit customer's information, What events I need take? ex: `adminhtml_customer_save_after` for admin right or wrong?
  +How I can send mail to customer when customer or admin change customer's information?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use below events for front-end and back-end/admin

Magento/Customer/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Save.php

```
adminhtml_customer_save_after
```

Magento/Customer/Model/ResourceModel/CustomerRepository.php

```
customer_save_after_data_object
```

For sending custom mail, you can use below resource to send an email by passing `Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder` into constructor.

[Magento2- Send custom transactional emails](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87940/magento2-send-custom-transactional-emails)

Comment: Dear krishna ijjada at i95Dev, When I take customer_save_after_data_object to take another edit information, Different user to create new account have been my action too. Do you known diffrent event?

Comment: Please tell me in more words.

Comment: customer_save_after_data_object is events be used in create new user and edit information user. Please tell how to take edit information customer only?

Comment: You can use http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132963/magento-2-event-after-customer-edit-account-and-address